# How to unzip an .sh file using a chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

Can you please share a sample chef recipe to execute a .sh file? The file is zipped in a folder, so i need to extract that first before executing(again using a recipe). I am facing a problem when trying to silent instal the .sh file. " -q " is not getting recognised by the recipe. The command im trying to execute is "sh .sh –q –varfile response.file "
I am able to install it successfully on the linux, but not using the recipe. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're after something like [`remote_file`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html) and two [`execute`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html) resources chained like this (assuming the zipped file contain files at it's root and is of type gzipped tar, update command accordingly):

```
execute "silent_install" do
  command "/path/to/package/script.sh -q -varfile /path/to/package/response.file"
  action :nothing
end

execute "unzip_package" do
  command "/bin/tar -xzf /path/to/package.tgz -C /path/to/package"
  action :nothing
  notifies :run,'execute[silent_install]', :immediately
end

remote_file "/path/to/package.tgz" do
  source "http://host/package-source.tgz" 
  notifies :run,'execute[unzip_package]', :immediately
end
```

**However** this is the kind of action an [`ark`](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ark) resource is far more suited to do and very less error prone and brittle.

Example with same kind of assumptions (keeping the execute of silent installer, should be better to include in a Makefile but this goes out of scope for this answer I think):

```
execute "silent_install" do
  command "/path/to/package/script.sh -q -varfile /path/to/package/response.file"
  action :nothing
end

ark 'mypackage' do
   url 'http://remote.host/package.tar.gz'
   path "/path/to"
   action :put
   notifies :run,'execute[silent_install]', :immediately
 end
```

Comment: Hi, the zip file is not tar file but a compressed file, since the file is very huge, im unable to convert it to .tar. Is there any command directly to unzip a compressed file? Also, there is no direct link to download the zip file, so the source path might not work. so can i place the zip file in cookbook/files/default and unzip that before silent installing?

Comment: Im pretty new to chef, so i need to write a recipe to copy the installation file from my local machine(for silent installation, i need to copy the response.varfile, the lisence file and the .sh file) and then unzip the file and then install it.

Comment: @user6039496 Command will be `unzip` instead of tar, or maybe just `gzip`. I would not recommend setting a large file in your cookbook, but if it's absolutely what you want you can see the `cookbook_file` resource (I let you search for it on the doc yourself). But I really recomend you to have a look at the `ark` cookbook which would manage for you the file type (tar/gzip/zip/bz2) and allow a better control over the process.